# Bubble sort using only pointers and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, bubble-sort

I am trying to run *Bubble Sort Technique* using pointers and dynamic memory allocation, but the code doesn't seem to run (eclipse crashes). Please help. I am posting the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void sort(int *);

//===========================================
int main()
{
    int *a = new int[5];
    int *c = a;

    cout << "Enter the numbers\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> *a;
        a++;
    }

    a = a - 4;

    sort(a);

    cout << c;
    cout<<"\nSorting complete";
    cout<<"\n Array after sorting";

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << *c << endl;
        c++;
    }

    delete []a;
    delete []c;

    a = c = NULL;

    return 0;
}
//===========================================
void sort(int *a)
{
    int *b = a + 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(*a > *b)
        {
            int temp = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = temp;
             a++;
             b++;
        }
        else  
        { 
            b++;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` (and sort out the indentation)

Comment: Why are you assigning the input like that? You should really be doing `cin>>*(a+i);` so that you're not doing more assignments and possibly trigger a range issue.

Comment: @edheal this is most likely a homework assignment and he can't use vectors

Comment: I am just trying out things in C++, as I am a newbie. It aint homework.

Comment: Either way - if homework it shows initiative. If not it shows knowledge

Comment: @iam-decoder, logically the code I have written to get input should be fine, I suppose.... As by pointer arithmetic, pointer + integer = pointer?

Comment: @EdHeal. I have not yet learnt abt vectors.,

Comment: True but you're doing so much more cleanup than you need to. What's the problem you have now? It looks like it's not going to actually sort anything or it won't be the correct values

Comment: Also for bubble sorting you need a second loop since the best time complexity for bubble sorting is O(n^2)

Comment: Please sort out the indentation and also where is the last bit of the code

Comment: @iam-decoder., You're right, I am not getting the result I desire. And Eclipse just hangs. And moreover, my question is if my approach correst, citing I want to use (pointers, dynamic memory allocation) to implement bubble sort.

Comment: It has to do with my original comment, you did your clean up wrong and attempted to access a memory address out of the allowable range for the variable

Comment: @EdHeal.., I ll do that. and about piece of code.., After the program exits the 'sort' function, I have displayed the array in the main function..,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a combination of small errors, and is unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: You have made this too complex. Start with a simple scenario such as int arr[5] = { 3, 5, 4, 2, 1 } and then call sort(arr) to sort it in place. Don't get input from the user, and don't use any dynamic allocation or freeing. Once you know how to implement bubble sort with a simple case, then you can add the other things back in if needed.

Comment: hmm, appreciate it.. thank you guys,.,

Comment: A KISS is the way to go - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @EdHeal.., thank you..,

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni - Please do not thank me - just read the article and comprehend

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int *a=new int[5];
int *c=a;
cout<<"Enter the numbers\n";
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  cin>>*a;
  a++;
}

a=a-4;
```

You increase `a` by 5, then reduce it by 4. You then try to sort starting from the 1 position but assuming 5 elements, so you march past the end of the array. If you correct this (e.g. `a=c;`), you will perform *one pass* of the bubble sort correctly (I think). You must perform more than one pass to sort the array fully.

**EDIT:** P.S. you are also trying to delete the array twice, which is unnecessary (and undefined behavior).

Comment: oh.., ok.. thanks for the help. I am a newbie. really appreciate your help.

And I thought, because I am using two pointers, that point to same thing (dynamic allocated memory) I thought I have to delete both the pointers.

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni: the phrase *"delete the pointer"* is misleading. When you call `delete` on a pointer, you delete **the thing pointed to**.

Comment: ok.., I guess I have to work on 'new' and 'delete' more closely... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make life easy

Get rid of code like

```
cin>>*a;
a++;
```

And use

```
cin>>a[i];
```

Use the same idea elsewhere

Comment: Hey, thanks man.., really appreciate it.., I ll work on that and keep you posted.,

Comment: Just hang on to the value returned by `new`. It makes life a lot simpler than messing around with pointers. Use `[]` notation