# Getting different outputs when running in Windows and Linux for a bubble sort in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn some C++ and noticed that when printing out an array in Windows (using CLion or Cygwin) the length variable overrides the last element in the array if I compile / execute in Windows.  When debugging, it's not clear why the length replaces the last element in the array.  But if I compile / execute in Ubuntu, I get the expected output.

Anyone know why this may be occurring?  I didn't change the code in any way.  I just compiled.

Code..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int myArray[] = {44, 9, 237, 1, 5, 44, 534, 17, 21, 819};
    int temp = -1;
    int end = 10;
    int length = 10;

    for(int counter = length - 1; counter > 0; counter-- ) {
        for(int index = 0; index < end; index++) {
            if( myArray[index] > myArray[index + 1]) {
                temp = myArray[index + 1];
                myArray[index + 1] = myArray[index];
                myArray[index] = temp;
            }
        }
        end--;
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        cout << myArray[index] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
```

Cygwin / Windows output...

```
1 5 9 10 17 21 44 44 237 534
```

Ubuntu output...

```
1 5 9 17 21 44 44 237 534 819
```

Comment: You should also look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711643/bubble-sort-using-only-pointers-and-dynamic-memory-allocation?noredirect=1#comment57170322_34711643

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Should be helpful

Comment: It is likely that the difference in the behavior of the uncorrected program was not because of the OS, but due to calling/local variables placement conventions, especially if you use 32-bit compilers on Windows and 64-bit on Linux.

Comment: Ok thanks Paulo.  I'll have to see the versions of compilers I have.  Instead of just grabbing what the video showed I switched the logic so that I don't reach beyond the array.  Didn't consider that the compilers can throw off things but makes sense

Answer (score 4):

`myArray[index + 1]` when `index` might be `end - 1` is undefined behaviour.

This is made worst by the fact that in most compiler implementation, `myArray[end]` might be at the same memory place as `temp`. `temp = myArray[index + 1]` is then dubious.

Comment: Gotcha.  I took the code from this link so expected it to be ok.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoVs1s0kfhE&index=7&list=PL034FA4BE70C727E0

Comment: If I keep running in Ubuntu, sometime it works and sometimes i get stack smashing error - so yeah I see what you mean.  Thanks

Comment: Is it great that people are now doing there coding and homework by not thinking too much but searching the internet.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm just pointing out the error, OP has to figure out what it was, how to solve it, etc. But I kind of agree with you.

Comment: @EdHeal - I'm not doing homework but thanks for your comment.  I'm actually just trying to learn some C++ by going through some tutorials online.  Perhaps you shouldn't make assumptions?

Comment: It is very similar to the other thread (see above). If I am incorrect I apologizes.

Comment: @EdHeal - No worries.  I was watching this video series on Youtube and the code is exactly the same.  I assumed it would work the same as it does for the guy in the video.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoVs1s0kfhE&index=7&list=PL034FA4BE70C727E0

Comment: Please do not believe all the crap on youtube

Comment: Hah well, you're right considering he left out some details